# Best way to replace strings

Tags: php, arrays, replace

I have an array where I'm storing the bad and good string pairs.
Ex.:

```
array(
"Man. United"=>"Manchester United",
"Bay. Munchen"=>"Bayern Munchen",
"Bay. Munich"=>"Bayern Munchen",
...
)
```

so in this case I'm using `strtr` to replace the given string, but in this case I always have to add or remove data's from the array. Is there any way to store just the good names in one array and replace which is very similar? For me is much easier to build up the array with the good names.

Comment: To potential answerers: `SuperMan. United` should not match.

Comment: So basically what you want is a spellchecker, right? I don't think there's a ready-made solution you can use, but you can perhaps find some info on how spellcheckers are built and use that. But of course, spellcheckers are also known for making mistakes all too "ducking" often, so it's tricky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [similar_text](http://php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php) or one of the other functions mentioned in the *see also* section to try and correct them automatically, but won't be as accurate as if you list the spelling mistakes yourself.

*edit: [levenshtein](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php) may also be a good one to try...

> The Levenshtein distance is defined as the minimal number of
>   characters you have to replace, insert or delete to transform str1
>   into str2.

Comment: how efficient is this function because in each 5minutes I have 5000 srtrings?

Comment: Levenshtein distance is a good tool, but it's also pretty "neutral" in that it doesn't really tell you if there's any similarity between the two strings to begin with. So comparing "apples" to "oranges" gives you a Levenshtein score of 5, which means... something. Point is you'll need to do a bunch of other checks for similarity and then Levenshtein can help pick the best match. Also, in the case of "Man. U" -> "Manchester United" for instance, the Levenshtein score will be terrible, since the two strings have very little in common.

Comment: I tried this solution but it's working very slow, +20seconds in 1000 string replace. I'm looking for, a faster solution. Are there any artificial solution?